# slick has empty slides at the end of slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a slick slider and at the end of a slider there are empty slides.

I have more than 10 images at the end of the slides I am getting empty slides.

```html
<div class="responsive slider">
    <div class=""><img src="brands/1.png"/></div>
    <div class=""><img src="brands/2.png"></div>
    <div class=""><img src="brands/3.png"/></div>
    <div class=""><img src="brands/4.png"></div>
    <div class=""><img src="brands/5.png"/></div>
    <div class=""><img src="brands/6.png"></div>
    <div class=""><img src="brands/7.png"/></div>
    <div class=""><img src="brands/8.png"></div>
    <div class=""><img src="brands/9.png"/></div>
    <div class=""><img src="brands/10.png"></div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.responsive').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: false,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 4,
  });
});
```

I am using [slick slider plugin](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

Comment: i fail to see how this is a php problem

Comment: isn't this `slidesToShow: 4,` an issue?

Comment: there is no php error..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also change the option `infinite` to `true` so two cloned slides (the two first slides) will fill the empty spaces.

Answer (score 4):

**First of all** you do not have more than 10 images, but exactly 10.

**Secondly** this is because you have `slidesToShow: 4` so obviously the last part of 4 images will have two empty slides, because 10 is not devidable by 4.

**Solution**

Either make number of images devidable by 4 or change `slidesToShow` so that the number of images is devidable by new value.